# Entering value to dynamically allocated memory at runtime

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

Following is the code I wrote for reading a value at run time to dynamically allocated memory:

```
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int *p = new int[5];
    int *a = new int();
    cin >> *a;   // **line 5**
    cout << *a << "\n"; //  **line 6**
    cout << &p;   // line 7
    cout << *p;    // line 8

    cout << "\nEnter 5 no for array\n";
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        cout << &p[i] << "  :-  ";
        cin >> p[i];   // LINE 12
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        cout << "\n" << p[i];     // LINE 16

    delete[] p;
    delete a;
    getch();
}
```

I would like to know that while entering data for user in integer, we have to use `*a` with `cin` and `cout` for entering data in line 5 & 6 but in case of array we just gave the pointer variable name in line 12 & 16. Can anyone please tell me why we are having this difference?

Moreover can anyone also please tell me the difference between output of line 7 & 8.

Comment: If it helps, `p[i]` is `*(p + i)`.

Comment: Your questions sound like you don't understand how pointers work. Pointers  point ot variables or locations, in memory, the & operator gets the address of the pointer, and the * derefernces the pointer to get the value stored in the pointers address. so when you cin>>*a you are reading something into the value of a. and when you cin>>7a you are reading in the address of a. Hopefully this helps you see the difference.>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> So the differnece in line 7 & 8 is that you are outputting the address on line 7 and outputting the value stored there in line 8.

Comment: One question per question please

Answer (score 0):

You don't "have to"; you could have written `cin >> a[0]`.

For built-in types and pointers and such, `a[b]` is `*(a+b)` is `*(b+a)` is `b[a]` and you can interchange them all.

It's only convention that leads to a choice. Like generally if you'd allocated more than one `int` you'd use "array notation" (`a[i]`) and if you'd allocated only one `int` you'd use a straight-up dereference (`*(a+0)`, or `*a`).

But the language doesn't really care how many elements you allocated because either way you just have a pointer to "one or more" consecutive elements.

tl;dr this is just how the syntax was designed.

As for your second question, `&p` and `*p` give different results because they mean different things, and I'll leave discerning that difference as an exercise to the reader.